# Does string.replaceAll() performance suffer from string immutability?

Tags: java, performance, string

Lets say I called replaceAll() on a big string that replaced 1,000 matching instances. Does it mean that 1,000 strings were created and reassigned in process because of string immutability?   Is there any faster alternatives?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you dig into [String](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html), you'll see that it delegates replaceAll() to [Pattern](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.java.html) & [Matcher](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.java.html) **and** Matcher.replaceAll() uses a StringBuilder to store the eventually returned value.

So no, String.replaceAll() does not create more than a small number of objects.

Comment: Keep in mind that creating a new Pattern may be expensive. Depending on how often it's being called, it may be more efficient to create the Pattern once and create a Matcher from that. As always, profiling your app will tell you if this is necessary or a premature optimization.

Answer (score -1):

you can try with a [StringBuffer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html)/[StringBuilder](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), since they are **mutable** [CharSequence](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html)s:

```
CharSequence veryBigString = new StringBuilder();
Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(veryBigString).replaceAll(replacement);
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if `veryBigString` is mutable; `replaceAll()` will still create a new StringBuffer to do the work, and return the result as a new String. Was that your point?